# r-In Shiny How to update datatable in a row

Tags: r, sqlite, datatables, shiny

I am writing a shiny app using DT::renderDataTable. I am using sqlite for getting the data and bind to the datatable. I want to update a cell in row in the code below:

```
server = function(input,output,session){
    output$List = renderDataTable(server=T,{
        db=dbgetQuery(connection,"select * from employee")
        datatable(db)
     })
     observeEvent(input$select_cancel_button, {
        //want to update here
     })
}
```

I have gone through several websites but didn't get any clue. should I re-render the datatable?

Comment: Do you want to update the source table in the SQLite database or only what is shown to the user? In the first case, you will have to use `dbSendQuery` or similar to update the source table.
Also, make sure to check your code inside the `renderDataTable` function, there are some mistakes (`server=T`, `dbgetQuery`)

Comment: I have a scope of updating the table. But not able to understand how reflected/changed data bind to datatable again.

Comment: If the event triggers an update of the database table, you will also have to re-render the datatable after the update is finished. Please provide a minimum working example if you need more specific help.